# how to pipe to a kdialog textbox?

Tags: command-line, kde, pipe

```
echo "hello" | kdialog --textbox -
```

I was hopping that row should pipe the word hello over to kdialog, and by setting the file argument to `-`, it should have used the piped text as content.

Is it possible to pipe the content to kdialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [here strings](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) to pass the text to `kdialog` stdin:

```
kdialog --textbox /dev/stdin <<< Hello
```

If you need to pass the output of a command you can use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
kdialog --textbox /dev/stdin <<< $(my_script.sh | sed_command)
```

Comment: as I have a script thats piped to sed, and then going to be displayed, so cant use here-strings. tried use `echo "hello" | kdialog --textbox /dev/stdin` but that didn't work :-(

Comment: @PugganSe: You could try this sort of command `kdialog --textbox /dev/stdin <<< $(my_script.sh | sed_command)`

Comment: The comment version works, but the answer version dosn't work, won't accept it unless you update it to the working soloution

Comment: @PugganSe: Sure thing, see my edit with command substitution